# Why the field in webbrowser is still consider as empty even I already set its value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBmRA.png)I'm trying to automate our ticketing system using visual basic. However, I can't save the profile because the field in webbrowser is still read as empty even I already set its value:

[image]

I also tried to set the attribute `originalvalue`, `prekeyvalue` etc. but still not working. But if you manual type the value in the field, it will work.

My code below:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mb8a86d99-tb").SetAttribute("value", "EMAIL")
```

The information of field below:

```
<input datatype="0" id="mb8a86d99-tb" aria-required="true" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="mb8a86d99-lb" class="fld text   fld fld_req" ctype="textbox" li="mb8a86d99-img" maxlength="512" style=";width:225.0px;" async="1" ae="setvalue" type="text" value="" ov="" work="1" fldinfo="{&quot;lookup&quot;:&quot;valuelist&quot;,&quot;dsid&quot;:&quot;TSDTKTSOURCE&quot;,&quot;inttype&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;afindex&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;length&quot;:&quot;512&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true}" title="" originalvalue="" prekeyvalue="" stoptcclick="true">
```

[image]

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are not the same thing. Please choose the correct tag and remove the other one.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem seems to occur in some web pages when the `form` containing your `input` does not get activated (it's a form of protection on client-side made to avoid the insertion of values programmatically).

If you manually type the value in it, the `form` turns active because you're clicking on the `input` which is a child of the `form`. However, if you do it programmatically, the activation is not triggered and so the value that you add to the HTML is not taken by the client.

You can try to emulate the activation of the form with the `Focus` method on your input:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mb8a86d99-tb").Focus
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mb8a86d99-tb").SetAttribute("value", "EMAIL")
```

If that still doesn't work, try to add a `Application.Wait(TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 2))` between one command and the other to let the form the time to actually activate itself.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. its already focused on the field but unfortunately it is still not working. I also tried to inspect element and insert a value in the inspect element but its also not working. It feels like it needs to detect that I am really typing and not just to insert value. Hoping further advised.

Comment: @Renan Have you tried to set a .Click() as well, before .Focus()?

Comment: yes. I guess there is a code hiding in the html to make it activate or to detect it that i'm typing in the field.

Comment: I tried to inspect element using firefox and I saw an event, but still I have no idea to make it work. I add the screenshot in my post

Comment: @Renan one of the events seem to be the “focus” event as suggested in my answer, but you said that it didn’t work right? Did you try adding a pause of 2 seconds in between? Else, you might try to fire all the other events in that list until when the input does not get active.

Comment: even I add 2 seconds delay, it is still not working. hitting also the events doesn't.

Comment: @Renan unfortunately we can't debug without the website. I suggest you open the website on  Google Chrome on a side, the HTML viewer on the other side, manually click on the box and check the HTML in order to see if you can figure out what event is being called.